# How to run an if check only once in a recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion

I am working on a program that prints the prime factorization of a user input. I am required to call an is_prime function each time I run the prime_factorization function. This is causing issues because after I run the prime factorization the number passed in to the function is changed.IE the first time through with an input of 14 it would return a 2, then it would have 7 left. This is a prime number so it does not pass the
`if(!is_prime(input))`  check on the second time through the function. My question is how can I only run that if check once and then skip it. I have tried booleans but I cannot implement it correctly. Thank you.

```
bool is_prime(int input){
    bool prime = true;
    if(input == 0 || input ==1){
        prime = false;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i <=input/2;i++) {
        if (input % i == 0) {
          prime = false;
            break;
        }
        
      }
    return prime;
}
void prime_factorization(int input){
    int num = 2;
        if(!is_prime(input)){
            while(input%num !=0) num++;
            cout << num << " ";
            prime_factorization(input/num);
        }
        else{
            cout <<"That is a prime number"<< endl;
        }
}
```

Comment: [Memoization](https://www.google.com/search?q=memoization) is the droid you are looking for.

Comment: In the `else` within `prime_factorization()`, a prime factor has been found.   Presumably you need to print that prime factor.   You're not.